# How to solve this false overfull warning?

Tags: koma-script, warnings

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,parskip=true]{scrartcl}

% PACKAGES LOADING

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % To customise font.
\usepackage{mathtools} % Math Packages
\usepackage[utopia]{newtxmath} % Best font ever.
\usepackage{erewhon} % By egreg's recommendation.
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1.5in,heightrounded]{geometry} % To custom layout.

\begin{document}

Let $\Gamma=\{\gamma\mid\gamma\text{ is a non-cooperative game}\}$ be the set of all non-cooperative games.

\end{document}
```

Compiling with Overleaf generates an `Overfull \hbox (3.57732pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 13--14` warning. However, the corresponding line does not even reach the end of its allotted horizontal space, and thus I don't know what `overfull` is LaTeX talking about nor how to solve it.

PS: I know I should not load `geometry` with KOMA Classes, but I don't know how to achieve the desired aspect ratio (and thus how to reproduce the warning) without loading it.

Thank you all for your help!

Comment: You could try adding the class option `usegeometry` (only a guess, can't test now).

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I didn't even know that option existed. I will try it, but I don't think this will remove the false warning, right?

Comment: Try to add the class option `overfullrule=true` and you will see the problem. With the class option `parskip=true`, _there
must be at least 1 em of free space at the end of the last line of the paragraph_ (extract from KOMA-Script documentation).

Comment: Use the class option `parskip=full-`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `parskip=true` option sets `\parfillskip` to a nonzero value for the fixed component. With your setup the value is

```
11.31674pt plus 1.0fil
```

that is, 1em at 11pt: at least 1em of blank space is required at the end of paragraphs. Thus your line *is* overfull.

Use `parskip=full-` or `parskip=half-` instead. Or no `parskip` at all.

By the way, there's nothing wrong in using `geometry` with KoMa classes.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer solved the problem.